# How do you run a binary file that neither Windows nor Cygwin can execute?

Tags: cygwin

I haven't loaded up a VM of Linux yet (I have OpenSUSE on a VM on my machine), but whenever I run the executable under Cygwin, I get the error message "cannot execute binary file". Windows (PowerShell) tells me that it can't find the command that is the file name, or if I use ./, it tells me that no application can open this file. Also, in Windows (Command Prompt), I get a message that says the file is not recognized as a command or operable program.

Note that I already used chmod on Cygwin to set the file to executable.

I have no idea what language this is in, but it's an executable. I'm trying to be able to execute this file on my local machine so I can complete the actual assignment that it is for, which is black-box testing the application. Unfortunately, I'll be traveling and don't want to rely on my school's servers when I won't have reliable Internet access until I'm back home.

Thanks for any suggestions on dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cygwin doesn't execute Linux executables, so you cannot just run a Linux binary that way.

In order to execute something under Cygwin, you need to specifically compile it for that.

Therefore, I think you're just going to have to run it on a Linux box or VM.

Comment: "In order to execute something under Cygwin, you need to specifically compile it for that." - well, not necessarily, it runs Windows apps normally.

Answer (score 6):

Use [a 'file' utility](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) to determine the type of binary first ...

Answer (score 2):

I think there are more information you need to know to run an application. is it 32bit or 64bit? executable compiled for windows or linux? what libraries/platforms/applications does it depend on?